# How does this address (0x00000400) = 1024

Tags: c++, memory, c-preprocessor, memory-address

Im working in C++ and I have a `#define VAL 0x00000400`. when I set a variable equal to the define: int value = VAL; when I run through the debugger is shows the variable value = 1024. could someone explain how that turns into 1024? Maybe some links to memory address info, #define info, or something relevant.

Comment: -1 for very basic question on the diff between base 10 and base 16.

Comment: oh, i can't imagine how peoples using hex without don't know anything about this

Comment: @Steve - +1 to counter your unnecessary downvote. SO is a place for questions, even if they are basic.

Comment: @Yuwal A: i want to see on SO more professional peoples than c++ tutorial questions

Comment: @Svisstack: Search engines aren't yet intelligent enough to bring up useful results for questions such as these. Until then, it's fine to post such questions here.

Comment: @Svisstack: Just because that's what you want doesn't mean that's what SO is for.  SO is meant to be a one-stop-shop for programming questions, not just those deemed "hard" or "interesting."  Besides, one programmer's hard or interesting question is another's tutorial question.  There's always someone smarter than you.

Comment: Interesting to see this back and forth.  I actually reconsidered my downvote, but can't see how to retract it without upvoting the question. Perhaps I should ask how to do this on SO?

Comment: @Steve - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40683/upvoting-a-downvoted-answer-will-do-2-upvote/40685#40685 - "To undo a vote, click the same vote you clicked earlier. ... Clicking the other vote is not really undoing, but changing -1 into +1, or +1 into -1."

Comment: Tried that.  I get a popup telling me that my vote is locked in unless the q is edited.  Bad karma for me, then.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

0x00000400 is base 16 for 1024.  Your debugger is showing you the integer value in base 10.

Answer (score 8):

"0x400" is [hexadecimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal), or base 16.  0x400 expressed as decimal (base 10), is 1024.

By the way, you can use google to do base conversions.  Search for ["0x400 in decimal"](http://www.google.com/search?q=0x400+in+decimal&btnG=Search) and google will give you the answer.

Comment: Upvoted for linking out while the top answer didn't bother to >_<

Answer (score 3):

0x00000400 is 400 base 16, which is 1024 base 10.

Answer (score 3):

1024 in decimal = 400 in hex.

Answer (score 3):

`0x400` is a hexadecimal number (indicated by the `0x` prefix.) It is another way of representing the decimal number `1024`.

Answer (score 3):

Additionally, the conversion from 0x400 (base 16) to base 10 is:

```
4*16^2 + 0*16^1 + 0*16^0
4*16^2 + 0 + 0
4*256
1024
```

Answer (score 0):

well, I haven't seen your code, but 400h = 1024 decimal and you specify integer ' int value = VAL ' compiler just does not display any notice/warning, it does the cast for you

Comment: I mean, it makes the conversion... implicitly